# How to make the part of search suggestion bold based on the user input?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, search, replace

I have been trying to develop a search suggestion in React. The search suggestions will be displayed as the user types.

You can find the code on the link - https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-shaw-rqp2k?file=/src/Autocomplete.js

What I want to achieve is that the suggestions appearing must have a part in bold that the user typed.

Example - When the user types "**pa**" in the input field, we get two suggestions- Papaya and Paw Paw

So, the suggestion should appear as **Pa**paya and **Pa**w Paw.

I have been trying to use the replace method to achieve that by doing something like below -

```
let optionName = optionName.replace(userInput,'<b>'+userInput+'</b>')
```

This piece of code is not working, which is line 66 on codesandbox link.

Any other solution which is not using the replace method is also welcome.

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked out. Please check.

```
<li className={className} key={optionName} onClick={onClick}>
                {_getStyledSuggestion(optionName)}
</li>
```

```
const _getStyledSuggestion = (suggestion) => {
    if(!suggestion.toLowerCase().startsWith(userInput)) {
      return <span>{suggestion}</span>;
    }
    const userInputLength = userInput.length;
    return(
      <span>
        <span className="bold-span">{suggestion.substring(0, userInputLength)}</span>
        {suggestion.substring(userInputLength)}
      </span>
    );
  }
```

CSS:

```
.bold-span {
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-sea-97k4w?file=/src/Autocomplete.js:1495-1898

Comment: Thank you so much @Gowtham ... really appreciate it :) .. Genius

Comment: If it is possible, can you please also tell me why it is not working using replace method?

Comment: The `replace` method returns a string, not a react element. If you look at `_getStyledSuggestion`, it's returning the `span` react element.

Comment: Got it... Thanks @Gowtham... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM

instead of:

```
  <li className={className} key={optionName} onClick={onClick}>
            {optionString}
  </li>
```

You can use:

```
<li className={className} key={optionName} onClick={onClick}>
                <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: optionString}}  />
</li>
```

Comment: Do you think it is safe to use it? I have read that it creates XSS vulnerabilities in our application

Comment: In this case yes because you are using it with html you have generated but never use it with any content that has come from an outside source.